# method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, gps, maps

Am trying to display a map but it displays this error,"The method getSupportFragmentMananger()is undefined for the type main"  Please Help. thanks. I am using Google maps ap

```
package com.maps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;



import android.app.Activity;

public class main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        GoogleMap mMap;
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        //can pass dynamic variables
        final LatLng place = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
       Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                  .position(place)
                                  .title("Melbourne")
                                  .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
                                  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(android.R.drawable.bottom_bar)));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
public class main extends Activity
```

you should use either `AppCompatActivity` or `FragmentActivity`, E.g.

`public class mai extends AppCompatActivity`

instead of

```
public class main extends Activity
```

Comment: ERROR: Cannot cast from Fragment to MapFragment

Comment: What happens is that when you extend Fragment Activity instead of Activity, it means that you will not be able to call your activity from another activity that does not extend Fragment activity and this becomes a challenge. I have tried to do this but what I have been getting is NoClassDefFoundError. In this instance how does one call the activity in another class